# Angular Material: mat-paginator navigation disabled when length changes

Tags: angular, angular-material, pagination, paginator

So basically, in my Angular app I have a list of elements (containing data retrieved from an API) that I'd like to control with mat-paginator. Here's what I've done:

**results.component.html**

```
<div class="results-list">
    <!-- Results list container. -->
    <div class="container">
      <app-result-card
        *ngFor="let result of results"
        [result]="result"/>
      <mat-paginator
        class="paginator"
        showFirstLastButtons
        (page)="handlePageEvent($event)"
        [length]="length"
        [pageSize]="pageSize"
        [pageIndex]="pageIndex"
        [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"/>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**results.component.ts**

```
export class ResultsComponent{
  public results: VM[] = [];  // Custom model.
  public length = 0;
  public pageSize = 5;
  public pageIndex = 0;
  public pageSizeOptions = [5, 10, 25];

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ){}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void{
    this.http.get<VM[]>("http://localhost:8080/vm/get").subscribe(data => {
      this.results = data;
      this.length = Math.ceil(this.results.length/this.pageSize);
    })
  }

  handlePageEvent(e: PageEvent){
    this.pageSize = e.pageSize;
    this.pageIndex = e.pageIndex;
    this.length = Math.ceil(this.results.length / this.pageSize);
  }
}
```

The problem is that whenever the `length` value gets changed, the navigation button to go to the next page disables itself. I tested it by initializing the `lenght` value to 50, the `pageIndex` value to 3 and by disabling the assignation inside `ngViewAfterInit`, and when the page loads the "next page" button is fine, but when I go to the previous page (and so I call the `handlePageEvent` function) and the length gets changed, that button instantly disables.
I've found [this example](https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/examples) (the "Configurable paginator") inside the documentation and, according to it, changing the length shouldn't be a problem. What am I doing wrong?